# How can I spawn as many requests as needed to get unique results from an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, axios

I'm working on an excercise to get different random results from an API using JavaScript.

Mi idea is to have an array of results I already got and issue as many asynchronous requests as I need to get the job done.

I tried using Axios and jQuery (I'm supposed to use the first one but it didn't work and since I'm more experienced with jQuery I decided to give it a try) but neither one works.

Here's my code:

```
let categories = [];

    function fillCatsWithAxios() {
            let spawn = 5;
            while (categories.length < 5) {
                    if (spawn) {
                            let offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
                            console.log('Spawning one with offset ' + offset);
                            axios.get('http://jservice.io/api/categories', {
                            params: {
                                    count: 1,
                                    offset: offset 
                            }
                            }).then(function(value) {
                                    let id = value.data[0].id;
                                    console.log('Got one! Id = ' + id );
                                    if (categories.indexOf(id) == -1) {
                                            console.log('A new one, adding');
                                            categories.push(id);
                                    } else {
                                            console.log('Duplicated, try again');
                                            spawn++;
                                    }
                            });
                            spawn--;
                    }
            }

            console.log(categories);
    }

function fillCatsWithJQuery() {
                let spawn = 5;
                while (categories.length < 5) {
                        if (spawn) {
                                let offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
                                console.log('Spawning one with offset ' + offset);
                                $.ajax({
                                        url: 'http://jservice.io/api/categories', 
                                        data: {
                                                count: 1,
                                                offset: offset 
                                        },
                                        success: function(value) {
                                                let id = value.data[0].id;
                                                console.log('Got one! Id = ' + id );
                                                if (categories.indexOf(id) == -1) {
                                                        console.log('A new one, adding');
                                                        categories.push(id);
                                                } else {
                                                        console.log('Duplicated, try again');
                                                        spawn++;
                                                }
                                        }});
                                spawn--;
                        }
                }

                console.log(categories);
        }
```

When I run this script on my browser I never see the message "Got one!" and looking at the developer's console I don't see any XHR being performed either :(

The strange thing is, if I change the while condition to something fixed (Like a fixed number of iterations) it works...

Any idea?

Comment: `while (categories.length < 5)` - this never completes.  Remember the `success:` call is async so can only run when a) the $.ajax has completed and b) when your js code has finished - there's no "interupts" - as there's nothing that changes `categories` outside the callback, this never completes and the js never gets a chance to make the ajax call.  Remove that line, fix the `value.data[0]` and it works fine (once) https://jsfiddle.net/1x57swm4/ then make a second(and subsequent) call from within the callback.

Comment: That's interesting... I wasn't aware of condition b), I thought it'd run in parallel... is there something like a "yield" or any other keyword that would allow the second thread to run?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded - only one thing can "run" at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @freedomn-m's comment I got to this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let categories = [];
    let spawn = 5;

    let catFiller = setInterval(function() {
            let offset;

            if ( categories.length < 5 ) {
                    for ( let i = 0; i < spawn; i++ ) {
                            offset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
                            console.log('Spawning one with offset ' + offset);
                            axios.get(
                                    'http://jservice.io/api/categories', 
                                    {
                                            params: {
                                                    count: 1,
                                                    offset: offset 
                                            }
                                    })
                                    .then(function(value) {
                                            let id = value.data[0].id;
                                            console.log('Got one! Id = ' + id );
                                            if (categories.indexOf(id) == -1) {
                                                    console.log('A new one, adding');
                                                    categories.push(id);
                                                    spawn--;
                                            } else {
                                                    console.log('Duplicated, try again');
                                            }
                                    });
                    }
            } else {
                    clearInterval(catFiller);
            }
    }, 1000 );
```

Which is doing what I wanted (although in a much more complicated way than I envisioned :)

Thanks!